# OAuth flow/protocol used when using SSO to access OKTA dashboard

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, okta

When a user enters their company username and password on the OKTA login page of their company dashboard so he/she can get access to apps on the OKTA dashboard as show below:

[image]

What OAuth flow/protocol is used? Is this an authentication code flow with PKCE that returns an identity token that is later sent to the OKTA dashboard backend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OIDC app, which uses authorization_code flow with PKCE. You can inspect your network tab while logging in, to find the following request `https://redacted.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/authorize?client_id=redacted&code_challenge=GpFYQtoQXn1S1NtDJCZGTIQ8x0LSazjZJzE4KQvwPM0&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=KLn05YhdZ87nJ4Jpbrxauo4oJQeaSV8ZLIVlBeiJT6eQSnvhuun6hvSYbE3E3dBr&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fredacted.oktapreview.com%2Fenduser%2Fcallback&response_type=code&state=If1z2jR0yCJunv0oXdzlxxAAMIoyNFsVpAuXSjZnSW5tE7vMJIL8EQEBMWqZL8xN&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20okta.users.read.self%20okta.users.manage.self%20okta.internal.enduser.read%20okta.internal.enduser.manage` which clearly supports my statement

Answer (score 1):

it could be either SAML or OIDC. If it is OIDC, it usually implements authorization code flow with or without PKCE.